# a topological property of the product topology

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, descriptive-set-theory

Let $G$ be a non discrete Polish group. Let $K$ be a compact set of $G$, $C$ a closed set of $G^n$ and $B$ an open set of $G^n$. Suppose $K^n\cap C\subseteq B$.
Prove that there is an open set of $G$, say $U$, such that $K\subseteq U$ and $U^n\cap C\subseteq B$.

Geometrically, I think it is quite clear but I can't prove it formally. It is clear that also $K^n\cap C$ is a compact of $G^n$. Maybe we need only that $G$ is an Hausdorff space but I'm not sure. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's true for discrete groups trivially. So being non-discrete seems somewhat irrelevant?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I don't understand, sorry. I need a proof in the non discrete case. I agree that for discrete groups is trivially true. Are you suggesting to eliminate the non discrete hypothesis from the question?

Comment: No, but for this part (of a presumably larger proof) it's not needed.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma ok you're right. Any ideas? Since $K$ is bounded, I thought to use a compatible metric $d$ and create $K$ using an union of closed disks, but I have many problems with the choice of the radius of the disks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d$ be a metric inducing the topology of $G$ and endow $G^n$ with the metric

$$d_{\infty}(x,y) = \max \,\{ d(x_k,y_k) : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant n\}.$$

Then $d_{\infty}$ induces the product topology on $G^n$ (see <sup>(1)</sup>).

Since $K^n \cap C$ is a compact subset of $B$, there is an $r > 0$ such that $B_{r}^{d_{\infty}}(K^n\cap C) \subseteq B$ (see <sup>(2)</sup>). The set

$$C_r = C \setminus B_r^{d_{\infty}}(K^n \cap C)$$

is closed and disjoint from $K^n$, so there is a $\rho > 0$ with $B_\rho^{d_{\infty}}(K^n) \cap C_r = \varnothing$ (see also <sup>(2)</sup>).

Choose $\varepsilon \in (0, \min \{r,\rho\})$, and set $U = B_{\varepsilon}^d(K)$. Then $U^n = B_{\varepsilon}^{d_{\infty}}(K^n)$, so $U^n \cap C_r = \varnothing$, hence

$$x \in U^n \cap C \implies x \in B_r^{d_{\infty}}(K^n \cap C) \implies x \in B.$$

---

<sup>(1)</sup> The open $d_{\infty}$-ball $B_r^{d_{\infty}}(x) = \{ y : d_{\infty}(x,y) < r\}$ is the product of the open $d$-balls of the same radius around the components of $x$,

$$B_r^{d_{\infty}}(x) = \prod_{k = 1}^n B_r^d(x_k),$$

so it is open in the product topology, and hence the topology induced by $d_{\infty}$ is at most as fine as the product topology. Conversely, if $U$ is open in the product topology, and $x\in U$, then for every $k$ there is an $r_k(x) > 0$ such that $$\prod_{k = 1}^n B^d_{r_k(x)}(x_k) \subseteq U.$$ Then $r(x) = \min \,\{ r_k(x) : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant n\} > 0$, and

$$B_{r(x)}^{d_{\infty}}(x) = \prod_{k = 1}^n B_{r(x)}^d(x_k) \subseteq \prod_{k = 1}^n B^d_{r_k(x)}(x_k) \subseteq U,$$

so $U = \bigcup\limits_{x\in U} B_{r(x)}^{d_{\infty}}(x)$ is also open in the topology induced by $d_{\infty}$, i.e. the topology induced by $d_{\infty}$ is at least as fine as the product topology.

<sup>(2)</sup> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. For $x\in X$ and a subset $A\subseteq X$, we define

$$\operatorname{dist}(x,A) = \inf \,\{ d(x,a) : a \in A\}.$$

Note that $\operatorname{dist}(x,\varnothing) = +\infty$ for all $x\in X$, but $\operatorname{dist}(x,A) < +\infty$ if $A\neq \varnothing$, and for $r \in (0,+\infty)$ we have $$r > \operatorname{dist}(x,A) \iff B_r(x) \cap A \neq \varnothing.$$

Since $B_r(x) \cap A = \varnothing \iff B_r(x) \cap \overline{A} = \varnothing$, this shows that $\operatorname{dist}(x,A) = \operatorname{dist}(x,\overline{A})$ for all $x\in X$ and $A \subseteq X$. Further note $\operatorname{dist}(x,A) = 0 \iff x \in \overline{A}$.

An important feature of $\operatorname{dist}(\,\cdot\,,A)$ is that these functions are continuous. If $A = \varnothing$, the function is constant, hence continuous. If $A\neq \varnothing$, we have

$$\operatorname{dist}(y,A) \leqslant d(y,a) \leqslant d(y,x) + d(x,a)\tag{1}$$

for every $a\in A$, the first inequality holds by definition of $\operatorname{dist}(y,A)$, and the second by the triangle inequality. Taking the infimum on the right hand side of $(1)$, it follows that

$$\operatorname{dist}(y,A) \leqslant d(y,x) + \operatorname{dist}(x,A).\tag{2}$$

Exchanging the roles of $x$ and $y$, we get

$$\operatorname{dist}(x,A) \leqslant d(x,y) + \operatorname{dist}(y,A),\tag{2'}$$

and the symmetry $d(y,x) = d(x,y)$ then yields

$$\lvert \operatorname{dist}(y,A) - \operatorname{dist}(x,A)\rvert \leqslant d(x,y),\tag{3}$$

which shows that $\operatorname{dist}(\,\cdot\,,A)$ is Lipschitz-continuous with Lipschitz constant $1$ for $A \neq \varnothing$.

For $A\subseteq X$ and $0 < r < +\infty$, we define the open $r$-neighbourhood of $A$ as

$$B_r(A) = \{ x\in X : \operatorname{dist}(x,A) < r\}$$

and note

$$B_r(A) = \{x \in X : B_r(x) \cap A \neq \varnothing\} = \bigcup_{a\in A} B_r(a).$$

The latter shows that $B_r(A)$ is indeed open, and since $B_r(\{x\}) = B_r(x)$ the notations are compatible (although it is of course an abuse of notation to use the same notation for different things).

For two subsets $L,M \subseteq X$, we set

$$\operatorname{dist}(L,M) = \inf\, \{\operatorname{dist}(x,M) : x\in L\} = \inf \, \{ d(x,y) : x \in L, y \in M\}.$$

The second formula shows the symmetry $\operatorname{dist}(L,M) = \operatorname{dist}(M,L)$.

Then for $0 < r < +\infty$ we have

$$B_r(L) \cap M = \varnothing \iff r \leqslant \operatorname{dist}(L,M).$$

For, by definition of $B_r(L)$, we have

\begin{align}
&& B_r(L) \cap M &= \varnothing\\
&\iff& \bigl(\forall x\in M\bigr)\bigl(\operatorname{dist}(x,L) &\geqslant r\bigr)\\
&\iff& \inf \, \{ \operatorname{dist}(x,L) : x \in M\} &\geqslant r\\
&\iff& \operatorname{dist}(M,L) &\geqslant r.
\end{align}

Now we note that if $M$ is compact and $L$ closed with $M \cap L = \varnothing$, then $\operatorname{dist}(M,L) > 0$. If $M = \varnothing$ or $L = \varnothing$, then $\operatorname{dist}(M,L) = +\infty$, so we need only consider nonempty sets. Since $M$ is a nonempty compact set, the continuous function $\operatorname{dist}(\,\cdot\,,L)$ attains its minimum on $M$, i.e. there is an $m_L\in M$ with

$$\operatorname{dist}(m_L,L) = \min \,\{ \operatorname{dist}(x,L) : x \in M\}.$$

Since $L$ is closed and $M\cap L = \varnothing$, we have $\operatorname{dist}(x,L) > 0$ for all $x\in M$, so

$$\operatorname{dist}(M,L) = \operatorname{dist}(m_L,L) > 0.$$

In the above argument, we apply this first for $M = K^n\cap C$ and $L = G^n\setminus B$, noting that $$B_r^{d_{\infty}}(K^n\cap C) \cap (G^n\setminus B) = \varnothing \iff B_r^{d_{\infty}}(K^n\cap C) \subseteq B,$$

and then for $M = K^n$ and $L = C_r$.

Comment: sorry I don't understand this: $G^n$ is endowed with the product topology. Are you sure that the metric $d_\infty$ induces on $G^n$ the product topology? thank you

Comment: Yes. An open $d_{\infty}$-ball of radius $r$ is the product of open $d$-balls of radius $r$, $$B^{d_{\infty}}_r(x) = \prod_{k = 1}^n B^d_r(x_k),$$ so the open $d_{\infty}$-balls form a basis of the product topology.

Comment: sorry, could you prove that an open $d_\infty$-ball of radius $r$ is the product of open $d$-balls of radius $r$ please? Because in general an open set of the product topology is not the product of open sets. thank you

Comment: We have $y \in B^{d_{\infty}}_r(x)$ if and only if $d_{\infty}(x,y) = \max \{d(x_k,y_k) : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant n\} < r$, and $\max \{d(x_k,y_k) : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant n\} < r \iff \bigl(\forall k\bigr)\bigl(d(x_k,y_k) < r\bigr)$. So $y\in B_r^{d_{\infty}}(x) \iff \bigl(\forall k\bigr)\bigl(y_k \in B_r^d(x_k)\bigr)$, which is $y\in \prod B_r^d(x_k)$.

Comment: A set is open in the product topology if and only if it is the union of some family of products of open sets. So all $d_{\infty}$-balls are open in the product topology, and all unions of $d_{\infty}$-balls too. That shows the topology induced by $d_{\infty}$ is at most as fine as the product topology. On the other hand, if $U$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ in the product topology, it contains a product $\prod B_{r_k}^d(x_k)$ of open $d$-balls around the components of $x$. Now let $r = \min \{r_k : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant n\}$ to see that $U$ contains a $d_{\infty}$-ball around $x$,

Comment: which shows the product topology is at most as fine as the topology induced by $d_{\infty}$.

Comment: I think it works, thank you very  much !

Comment: Last thing about your notation: for $B_r(K)$ you mean an open ball of radius $r$ that contains $K$ right?

Comment: $B_r(K)$ is the set of points whose distance to $K$ is less than $r$, $$B_r(K) = \bigcup_{x\in K} B_r(x) = \{ y : B_r(y) \cap K \neq \varnothing\} = \{ y : \operatorname{dist}(y,K) < r\}.$$ Sorry, I forgot that that notation isn't universal.

Comment: sorry I'm literally studying (and admiring) your proof: why is there $\rho$ such that $B_\rho^{d_\infty}(K^n)\cap C_r=\emptyset$?

Comment: $C_r$ is closed, and $K^n \cap C_r = \varnothing$. Since $C_r$ is closed, we have $\operatorname{dist}(x,C_r) > 0$ for every $x \in G^n \setminus C_r$. The continuous function $x \mapsto \operatorname{dist}(x,C_r)$ attains its minimum - denote it by $\operatorname{dist}(K^n,C_r)$ - on the compact set $K^n$, and since $K^n\cap C_r = \varnothing$, that minimum is strictly positive. If $\rho \leqslant \operatorname{dist}(K^n,C_r)$, it follows that $B_\rho^{d_{\infty}}(K^n) \cap C_r = \varnothing$.

Comment: After this I will finish I promise: why is there $r$ such that $B_r^{d_\infty}(K^n\cap C)\subseteq B$ ? I thought you used the fact that $K^n\cap C$ is totally bounded as compact of $G^n$ but this does not work for $B$ because $B$ it is not a complete space.

Comment: Finish when you have understood everything, not before. It's the same argument as before, just with different sets. $B$ is open, so $\operatorname{dist}(x, G^n\setminus B) > 0$ for every $x \in B$. $K^n \cap C$ is compact, so - unless $K^n \cap C = \varnothing$ - there is an $x \in K^n\cap C$ with $$r_0 :=\operatorname{dist}(x, G^n\setminus B) = \min \{ \operatorname{dist}(y, G^n\setminus B) : y \in K^n \cap C\} = \operatorname{dist}(K^n \cap C, G^n\setminus B).$$ Since $K^n \cap C \subset B$ it follows that $r_0 > 0$. Then any $r \in (0,r_0]$ will do.

Comment: If $K^n \cap C = \varnothing$, then $B_r^{d_{\infty}}(K^n \cap C) = \varnothing$ for all $r$, so the inclusion is then trivially given.

Comment: Please could you prove explicitely that: 1) $B_\rho^{d_\infty}(K^N)\cap C_r=\emptyset$ ? and 2) $B_r^{d_\infty}(K^n\cap C)\subseteq B$? Of course consider $r$ and $\rho$ as in your comments. thank you again

Comment: of course in 1) $N$ is $n$. The inclusion in 2) is trivial if $K^n\cap C=\emptyset$. For you $dist(y,X)=inf\{d(y,x):x\in X\}$ right?

Comment: I've added some more details to the answer, including a proof that $B_\rho^{d_{\infty}}(K^n) \cap C_r = \varnothing$ and $B_r^{d_{\infty}}(K^n\cap C) \subseteq B$ (though in a more general setting). If anything remains unclear, please ask. Yes, exactly, $\operatorname{dist}(y,X) = \inf \{ d(y,x) : x \in X\}$.

Comment: To Daniel Fischer: would you mind to help me with this question? I ask you because you answered very well last time and the topic is very analytical and connected to complex analysis in a certain sense, please.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2105155/two-exercises-on-characters-on-marcus-part-2?noredirect=1&lq=1